# File Descriptor 0

Tags: c, linux, stdin, file-descriptor

Drawing from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3816774/is-the-file-pointed-by-stdin-file-descriptor-the-same-file-for-different-process) discussing file descriptors and tables;

**I want to know how stdin (that is, file descriptor 0, not C's stdin FILE structure) is handled within shells.**

When I run a piece of code like `read(0, buffer, 1024)` in C, which by default in C file descriptor 0 is connected to keyboard, the shell allows me to type text in, because, we assume, read is waiting to read the contents of the character device 'standard input', aka the keyboard. But wouldn't standard input simply be empty and produce that as its result? Alright, so let's say that 'connected to keyboard' path is the way of explaining it; if that's the case, then that must mean shells line buffer their command's, right? Calling a read on file descriptor 0 would mean that file descriptor 0 in a shell is connected to this line-buffered buffer output of standard input, and not directly to the keyboard, so what's making C wait around? Furthermore, why can we not use `lseek()` on standard input - does said 'file' always get overwritten every 'write' that's made to it and therefore there is nothing to seek around in as standard input (being the keyboard) is not really a file on a storage device per se?

Comment: C doesn't know anything about "keyboards" - it just knows about `stdin`, which is a stream of bytes. It uses blocking I/O for reads, which means that if there are no characters available on `stdin` to be read then it just waits until there are.

Comment: Being "empty" and "waiting around" are not mutually exclusive. What matters is whether a file descriptor is *open*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
read(0, buffer, 1024)
```

is a system call, a call into kernel code. The kernel's implementation of `read` will dispatch to the terminal (or pseudo-terminal) device driver, which will wait until you've either typed 1024 characters, a newline, or an EOF marker, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

> then that must mean shells line buffer their command's, right?

The buffering is performed in the terminal driver, if the terminal is set to the right mode. Otherwise, the program will just wait until 1024 bytes are entered.

> Furthermore, why can we not use `lseek()` on standard input

You can if stdin is a regular file. You just can't seek on a terminal, because that would require the terminal driver to remember *all* data that passed through the terminal device since it was created.

Comment: It's entirely possible to close and reopen 0 as a regular file. Or as a network socket, or a timerfd. The upshot is that you *cannot know* whether it's seekable unless you query it for that property.

Comment: Also, `stdin` is different from "fd 0". It's possible that C says that you cannot seek in `stdin` (at least it's UB to flush it), but that's unrelated to the Posix file API.

Comment: @KerrekSB I'm using the OP's definition, "file descriptor 0, not C's stdin FILE structure". It's quite idiomatic to call fd0 "stdin". Is there anything specifically wrong in my answer that you think I should fix?

Comment: You can call it `STDIN_FILENO` :-) I would just try to be clear about the distinction between the Posix API and the C standard library. Each have their own set of constraints and rules. I'm not 100% sure about the C library at the moment, but I think the OP is asking about Posix.

Comment: Right-O: I forgot that fd0-2 are, generally, connected to /dev/tty.  But when I call that same read function, I get something akin to 'line buffered' input: is this what's called "Canonical input"? - http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Canonical-or-Not.html#Canonical-or-Not